# Describing the zero level set of a harmonic function

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

Let $p(k)$ be a complex polynomial of degree $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $A=\{k\in\mathbb{C}:\text{Re}\,p(k)=0\}$

The harmonic function $\text{Re}\,p(k)$ determines the behaviour of $A$. Fix $z\in A$. If atleast one of the partial derivatives $\partial_{\text{Re}\, k}\text{Re}\,p(z)$ or $\partial_{\text{Im}\, k}\text{Re}\,p(z)$ are not equal to zero, then the implicit function theorem gives that in every neighbourhood of such a point $z$, there exist a smooth curve such that $\text{Re}\,p=0$ on that curve in that neighbourhood. This only fails when both the partial derivatives are zero. But in the latter case due to Cauchy–Riemann equations $\frac{d}{dk}p(z)=0$ and this only occurs at a finite number of points.

Can someone help me describe what happens at a neighborhood of a point $z\in A$ where $\frac{d}{dk}p(z)=0$? Also is there some flaws in the above argument?

Answer (score 3):

Your reasoning is correct. I think it's better to focus on the polynomial $p$ itself rather than its real part. You are considering the preimage of the imaginary axis under $p$.

In what follows, $p$ can be any holomorphic function, not necessarily a polynomial.

Two facts about holomorphic functions:

1. If $p'(a)\ne 0$, then $a$ has a neighborhood $U$ such that $p:U\to p(U)$ is a diffeomorphism. Hence $\{\operatorname{Re}p=0\}$ is an analytic curve near $a$.
2. Suppose $p'(a)=0$. Let $k$ be the smallest integer such that $p^{(k)}(a)\ne 0$. Then the Taylor expansion of $p$ about $a$ is  $$p(z)-p(a) = c_{k} (z-a)^{k} +\dots = (z-a)^{k}q(z)$$
   where $q$ is holomorphic and $q(a)\ne 0$. Let $g(z)=(z-a)q(z)^{1/k}$ (for some branch of fractional power; this is possible because $q(a)\ne 0$).  Note that $g'(a)\ne 0$. Since $p = p(a) + g^k$, the part of the set $\{\operatorname{Re} p=0\}$ near $a$ is  the preimage of the set $\{w:\operatorname{Re} w^k = 0 \}$ under $g$ (which is a diffeomorphism). That is, it is the union of $k$ analytic curves passing through $a$ and crossing at equal angles.

Example: $p(z)=z^3+z^4$, neighborhood of $0$.

[image]

Related post: [Smoothness of level curves](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68738/smoothness-of-level-curves)

Comment: So this seems to be a more direct way of understanding the zero level set. Seems nice indeed, however i must admit i never heard of __diffeomorphism__ before, and reading about it on Wikipedia quickly tells me that this argument is way to sophisticated for me to understand at the moment. Could you tell me where i can read more about this in a systematic way? @Normal

Comment: Corrected the typo. A diffeomorphism is a map that is differentiable and has differentiable inverse. Typically, this language appears in the statement of the inverse function theorem, which itself precedes the study of the implicit function theorem mentioned in your post.